How to set ENVFILE in Terminal to generate Android Release AAB in React Native Expo?
I am finding it difficult to generate an AAB file from a React Native Expo Project that consist some env variables, the problem that it generates when I try to normally build an aab but the env are not applied and they come as undefined.

have a .env file in your project root directory with your environment variables defined. For Expo projects, environment variables that you want to use in your JavaScript code should be prefixed with EXPO_PUBLIC_.
Also, in your eas.json file, you need to specify the ENVFILE to use for your build profile
environment variables are embedded into your JavaScript bundle at build time, so you need to rebuild your app if you change the values.

Currently the .env file is like this:
REACT_APP_API_URL=
REACT_APP_VEHICLE_IMAGE_URL=
